# Alternate column colors in SQL 2012 Matrix report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012

My requirement is, need to add alternate column color like Light Grey for one set of date and white for other Set, this should be reflected for the total matrix. I have tried  doing the following but was not successful.

I tried in a diffent format please see this, changed my actual Data string with a Rank function and started using that group.

Update your dataset string like the following:

```
select ColumnA,
       ColumnB,
       ColumnC,
       ColumnP,
       dense_rank()over(order by ColumnP)  as Row_num
from TableName
```

Click the handle of the row details and Use `=IIF(Fields!Row_num.Value mod 2 ,"White","Gray")` in the background property

This works pretty well, but only problem is, please see below:

[image]

When I use the Expression `=IIF(Fields!Row_num.Value  mod 2 ,"White","Gray")` , its providing me proper results but its colouring if there are empty field values, I do not want to do it, irrespective of the field values I need to color the column sets.

Could some one help me out with it in order to get the right thing.

Comment: Try with `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: I'm not 100% clear what is the issue

Comment: Issue is, if you see the first column set with grey color it should be White in color. But as there are blank values in those fields its  coloring them to grey. I need to find a way to make sure if there are blanks or not it would be White/Grey/White /Grey coloring in the entire column set for each date grouping.